# JBoss VPS External ip settings - working fine in local browser but not in external

Tags: jboss, ip, external, vps, host

On beforehand I have to say i'm a bit of a newbie.

I've sucscribed to a VPS with Ubuntu 11.04 server, I installed Jboss and am starting it with the -b 0.0.0.0 option.

Now if I lookup the address ip:8080 on a browser on the VPS itself it's working fine, but if I try to look it up on a browser on an external machine it isn't able to access the page.

I tried to modify the hosts file but without success. Maybe its the iptables? Or something else?

I really appreciate any help thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Take the static IP of the server, ping that from your command line tool with ping. If you are successful in pinging the server you are all set. Now go to the browser of the external pc and type the static ip and give the port as 8080. It will certainly work.

Some good suggestion from my side is, try PaaS(platform as a service) now as that is much easier than VPS and you will get up and running in minutes. Try [Jelastic](http://jelastic.com). It has got JBoss hosting. Deploy your WAR file there and you can access it immediately. Ket me know if you really go ahead and use it.

Surya